# What does "let name(param1, param2) = .." mean in ocaml (as opposed to just let name = ...)?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlyacc

I'm looking at a compiler written for a extremely pared down version of C. I'm new to ocaml, and am particularly confused about this structure

```
let check (globals, functions) =
(* A bunch of stuff abstracted out *)
  let check_function ...
   .... (*A b bunch of stuff abstracted out*)
in (globals, List.map check_function functions)
```

Where globals is a list of (var_type, var_name) and functions is a function records. I didn't post the entire file (it's very long) and my question is just about the outermost let statement.

I've always only seen simple let statements where you might have something like

```
let name = expr1 in expr2
```

So what does it mean when you have

```
let name(param1, param2) = expr1 in (param1, expr1 param2)
```

Kind of similar to what I have here?

Comment: You're misinterpreting the code because you've cut out most of it. The `in` is most likely attached to `check_function`, not `check`. So it's just a function, taking a tuple and returning a tuple. Have you ever considered looking at some documentation for a language you're trying to read? Even if just a cheat sheet like [this](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/ocaml/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let name(param1, param2) = expr1 in (param1, expr1 param2)
```

Would be perhaps more clearly written as:

```
let name (param1, param2) = 
  expr1 
in 
  (param1, expr1 param2)
```

That extra space makes it more apparent that `name` is a function which takes one argument. That argument is a tuple of two values `param1` and `param2`. It is locally bound only for the expression `(param1, expr1 param2)` which does not use this `name` function.

The `param1` and `param2` names are not used in the expression `expr1` *(they might as well be `(_, _)`)* and are out of scope when we get to the expression `(param1, expr1 param2)` so if this is valid code, they refer to bindings from **before** the code you've shown us.

Effectively `name` does nothing at all.